# Perl File::Copy is not actually copying the file

Tags: perl

**Quick synopsis**: Let's say there are multiple of the same file type in one directory (in this example, 10 .txt files). I am trying to use Perl's copy function to copy 5 of them into a new directory, then zip up that directory.

The code works...except the folder that is supposed to have the .txt files copied, doesn't actually have anything in it, and I don't know why. Here is my complete code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Copy;

my $source_dir = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\test";
my $dest_dir = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\files";
my $count = 0;

opendir(DIR, $source_dir) or die $!;
system('mkdir files');

while (my $file = readdir(DIR)) {
    print "$file\n";
    if ($count eq 5) {
        last;
    }

    if ($file =~ /\.txt/) {
        copy("$file", "$dest_dir/$file");
        $count++;
    }
}

closedir DIR;

system('"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\jar.exe" -cMf files.zip files');

system('del /S /F /Q files');
system('rmdir files');
```

Everything works...the directory `files` is created, then zipped up into files.zip...when I open the zip file, the `files` directory is empty, so it's as if the copy statement didn't copy anything over.

In the `$source_dir` are 10 `.txt` files, like this (for testing purposes):

- test1.txt
- test2.txt
- test3.txt
- test4.txt
- test5.txt
- test6.txt
- test7.txt
- test8.txt
- test9.txt
- test10.txt

The files don't actually get copied over...***NOTE:*** the `print "$file\n"` was added for testing, and it indeed is printing out `test1.txt`, `test2.txt`, etc. up to `test6.txt` so I know that it is *finding* the files, just not *copying* them over.

Any thoughts as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: "The code works." "Everything works." Impossible! It doesn't even compile!

Comment: Hint: `readdir` does not return a full path

Comment: Is it because `copy` was never called, or because it returned an error? If it's the latter, what error did it return?

Comment: @MattJacob fixed, haha. Good catch.

Comment: @RustyX, That won't affect the above program except for `closedir`.

Comment: @MattJacob Thanks! That was a good hint. I knew it was something small that I was missing.

Comment: So, so you use `system 'mkdir ...'` *and* `File::Copy` ... That's rather incongruous ... In fact, why not just replace the whole script with a simple `system xcopy => ...`? This would be a four line batch file. Or just use `Path::Tiny`.

Comment: Using `jar cMf` to create a zip file? Really? How do you create your jar files?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a typo in your script: 
    `system('mkdir files');`
should be:
    `system("mkdir $dest_dir");`

but, the real issue is that you are not using the full path of the source file. Change your copy to:
    `copy("$source_dir/$file", $dest_dir);`

and see if that helps.
You might also want to look at: File::Path and Archive::Zip, they would eliminate the system calls.

Comment: *"`system('mkdir files');` should be: `system("mkdir $dest_dir");`"* No it shouldn't. It should be `mkdir $dest_dir;`. It's ridiculous to fork and execute a bash process just to do something that is part of Perl in the first place.